# how to slow down sftp on Linux

Tags: linux, sftp, web-hosting

I am maintaining a community web site on a hosting company. Once every two weeks I need to download a backup to my home Linux host as an offsite backup. The backup is about 110M bytes total. My site otherwise is idle.

I use sftp to download. This download triggers an alert in the hosting company: IO or network is over limit. The limit is 5M bytes or bits per second. The hosting company then automatically shuts down my website.

My sftp command is very generic

```
sftp myname@mysite <<EOF
   get -p file1_100M
   get -p file2_5M
EOF
```

I see a lot posts about speeding up the file transfer. My goal is actually to slow it down, as much as possible.

My Linux is Ubuntu 18. The hosting company also uses Linux in a LAMP stack (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) with standard C-panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `sftp` but you can use `scp` with specific [command line](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) parameter:

> -l limit
> Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.

So you command will be:

```
scp -l 5000 myname@mysite:file1_100M .
```

Comment: this is an interesting suggestion. I need to check whether I can use the scp to connect to the hosting company

Comment: actually following your lead, i can see sftp also has '-l limit' option. great!!!

Comment: @oldpride, in such case use it :)